# Should I be worried if I missed the studs while mounting my TV?

Tags: drywall, mounting

I think I missed the studs based on how easily the drill moved through the drywall. My LCD only weighs 27lbs and the mount itself is 5lbs (rated to hold 165lbs, and uses 4 8mm lag bolts). I pulled as hard as I could downward on the tv and nothing moved at all, everything seems pretty sturdy.  Should I be worried? Is there something I can test in a week or so, to see if it will continue to hold strong?

Comment: 30 lbs is a lot of weight to fall off the wall. Pulling down isn't the same thing as pulling out and over time if the bolts aren't doing anything but holding in shear against sheetrock, it will fail.

Comment: The mount is only rated to hold 165lbs, if it's mounted according to the installation instructions (which likely include bolting it to a stud).

Comment: I've yet to see a TV mount that didn't say that the mount should be attached to the studs.

Comment: Since you've taken the time to ask here, you'll end up kicking yourself if you do not now remount the tv.

Comment: IT IS POSSIBLE that you actually did hit the studs. If you pulled downward as hard as you could on the mounted TV, I would think you would rip it right out. Before you remount the TV, you could try borrowing a good quality stud finder to double check. In the meantime it might be best to remove the TV from the mount and just leave the wall mount up there.

Comment: @Stainsor raises a good point - I'd imagine it'd freely wobble if ONLY through the drywall, let along pulling on it. Some drill bits on a half decent drill will cut through wooden studs like butter. Based on that, I'd probably just try and double check the studs are where you thought they were, rather than taking everything down. Of course, if you have the slightest feeling that any of them are not through studs (ESPECIALLY if you think you missed top and bottom on one side, for example) I would get it down and go again.

Comment: I know someone personally who cam back home to a fallen TV and a dog and a dead dog. Don't be that person - do it right.

Answer (score 24):

Your TV is being supported by two pieces of paper. That should be all you need to know.

The white plaster material in the middle of drywall resists compression. The interaction between the shaft of the bolts and the inner plaster is keeping the load from shearing straight down the wall and will support a significant load.

However, on the front and back of the drywall are two sheets of paper that resists tension, similar to the purpose of rebar in concrete. And the interaction between the threads of the bolts and these two sheets of paper are all that are preventing your TV from being pulled out of the wall. Over time, the top bolts will pull out from vibration, temperature and humidity changes, and especially if you adjust the angle of the TV.

Once those top bolts start to pull through, the paper will tear, the plaster will shear out of the hole, and the TV will only be supported by the lower bolts under a highly leveraged load. Those lower bolts will immediately fail, and you'll have a broken TV on the floor at best, or a broken person that was hit by the TV at worst.

So, as everyone else has already said, remount the TV to proper structure.

Answer (score 17):

Gypsum board (*drywall, plasterboard, wallboard*) is not a structural material, its only purposes are to prevent you from seeing into the next room and to conceal utility lines and structural members within the wall.

Drywall anchors are great for hanging small picture frames, little decorative shelves, and other similar knickknacks, they are not for hanging heavy expensive things like televisions.

When hanging any heavy object on a wall/ceiling, you should **always** anchor the object to structural members.  If there are no structural members where you want the object, you'll have to make a brace or bracket that can attach to the structural members and attach the object to that.  This brace/bracket can be either built into the wall (concealed), or attached to the outside of the wall (visible). In either case, it must be sturdily attached to the structural members of the wall/ceiling.

My advice to you would be to take the TV down, and remount it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you drill pilot holes? If so, you usually get wood chips coming out and can tell if you've hit the studs.

If you just used the lag bolts to attach, I would be nervous about the TV. It partly depends on how bad it would be if it came loose. Is this a super-expensive TV that is right above your child's play area? Or is it just a small in a corner where nobody will bump it? You should also consider pull-out strength, not just straight down. E.g. if the corner of the TV catches on a passerby and they pull it away from the wall.

Personally I would remove the lag bolts and either move the mount onto studs if possible or use drywall anchors instead. (You maybe also should consider why you "missed the studs"—did you just drill and hope you'd get them? There are ways to tell where they are.) You can probably use the drywall anchors in the same location as the holes from the bolts.

**EDIT** I'm talking about the drywall anchors that open up inside the wall cavity like [these, which have a 79 lb pull-out strength](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051IB63Q), not the [wimpy ones you just push into the pilot hole](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WE9XUY).

Comment: Don't use drywall anchors for this, or worst case at least get it in one stud

Comment: A 30 lb TV is well within the capacity for a single drywall anchor. I assume the mounting bracket has at least 4 fastener points. What's the problem? I've used plastic drywall anchors to comfortable hold pantry shelves full of food. I agree a stud is preferable.

Comment: +1 Agreed, flare out drywall anchors are acceptable if studs are not available where you would like the TV to be mounted.

Comment: @HenryJackson A drywall anchor can hold 30 pounds ONLY if the drywall around the anchor is stable.  If the drywall around the anchor gets damaged, the anchor is useless.  FIND A STUD

Comment: To add to what @TheEvilGreebo said, also depends on the thickness of the drywall.  5/8" will hold a lot more than 1/2 or 1/4".  Also assumes there's never been a hole there before and that you're not close to or on a seam, and that the drywall itself was properly anchored to the studs.

Comment: Other factors affecting anchor strength is whether the anchors are primarily in shear, or if there is a withdrawal component. Also the spacing of fasteners is a factor, 2 anchors an inch apart are hardly stronger than one. Under proper conditions, drywall anchors can suffice. However, if anchoring at least one fastener in a stud is so undesirable, it should be possible to attach plywood reinforcing to studs, and the TV will cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though latest TVs are pretty light, you're not going to get insurance if you don't mount it on studs like you're supposed to. Use a stud finder and pre-drill pilot holes to be sure you got the studs. Your bracket will very likely have holes aligning at a regular stud width, so no need to pull off the drywall to install additional bracing. All you might end up with is a couple of tiny holes to patch up but you'll have peace of mind it will not come off by accident.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some large toggle bolts and the TV isn't very heavy, you should be fine.

I built a wooden cabinet and filled it full of canned goods. I realized I couldn't get it where I wanted it while also having it on the studs, so I bought the biggest toggle bolts I could find and mounted it straight into the drywall with six of those bolts. It held just fine, even when filled with canned goods for a whole year.

So toggle bolts are always an option as long as the drywall is in good shape. There's also something called Snap Toggle that may be even better.