# How do I mount my TV on my wall with poor stud location?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs

My wall studs are in an inconvenient space, I had a spot on the wall where I envisioned the TV to go, but the location of the studs would not have this tv be in the center of it, and there is other furniture blocking if I put the tv up on the location of the studs.

My TV is only 45 lbs, although 55 inches, can this go into drywall? A lot of drywall only things I see recommend around 50-60lbs before things get questionable.

Additionally, I could get a wall mount that allows for more flexibility

any insight into a solution for this dilemma is appreciated

Comment: Is your question whether you can mount your TV to drywall? No. That's been addressed here already. [Quite](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2207/2196) [a few](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6725/2196) [times](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/20723/2196).

Comment: Is there an issue with taking a horizontal board to span your studs and then put your TV where you want attached to that?

Comment: @DMoore I would be able to do that, I suppose...

Comment: a good stud finder is cheaper than a TV (falling off and needing to be replaced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your budget, most TV mounts for large TVs have enough leeway to be installed even where the studs are not centered behind the TV. I installed a 65" TV on a wall where the studs were off center relative to the wall unit. The back plate was over 2 feet long, which allowed me to easily hit two of them. In my case I wanted a mount with articulating arms to make it easier to push the TV back into the wall unit so this made it easier as well...however either way it looks like it would have worked even in the "worst case" with a stud right in the center of where I wanted the TV. (My studs were 16" apart though, it would be more difficult if yours are further apart)

Comment: yeah my wall mount is 28 inches, I would need one a little longer or do the horizontal board trick someone else mentioned